# Core Data syncing

Tags: database, cocoa, macos, core-data, synchronization

is there a way to automatically sync my Core Data Model with a server (preferably REST)?

Thanks

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035132/how-to-sync-iphone-core-data-with-web-server-and-then-push-to-other-devices/5052208#5052208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has shared their Sync Services Framework it is documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SyncServices/SyncServices.html

This section is specifically related to syncing managed objects:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SyncServices/Articles/UsingCoreData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005232

As for which style of data transfer is used, I'm not sure if it using REST, I don't see it immediately obvious.

Typically the data transferred to and from REST services doesn't include large binary objects or complex data structures.  If REST is a requirement you may need to do something custom, but search through the available documentation you might find everything you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem is, that Sync Services isn't available on the iPhone, as I've read recently. :-(